# Bind to existing service with Android Annotations?

Tags: java, android, service, annotations, android-annotations

Docs [enter link description here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance%20Services) say how to start and finish service. Is there any way to bind with existing one with android annotation?

Answer (score 2):

When you bind to your `Service`, simply use the generated class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService_.class); // note the underscore
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Or you can use the generated `Intent` builder:

```
bindService(MyService_.intent(this).get(), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```